# Is it possible to override the theme sizes of NativeBase to obtain rem units?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components, native-base, styled-system

I'm new to [NativeBase](https://nativebase.io/) and I'm overriding the default theme to obtain a custom one where I would like to use `rem` units. I'm using the `extendTheme` function as [described in the docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/customizing-theme):

```
const myCustomTheme = extendTheme({
  sizes: {
    0: 0,
    1: 16,
    2: 32,
    // and so on
  }
})
```

However, if I try to use it in an element, the sizing stays the same.

At the moment I created a workaround by using a function to mimic the same effect:

```
const rem = (r: number) => `${r * 16}px`
```

So I can

```
<Button mb={rem(2)}>My Button</Button>
```

But this is not very nice to use.

Do you know how could I use `rem` units in a similar way without requiring this function, with a syntax like this

```
<Button mb={2}>My Button</Button>
```

or even better like this

```
<Button mb="2rem">My Button</Button>
```

that uses rem units?

*I tested this only using the iOS simulator, so I don't know if it would have worked worked differently on Android or Web.*

Original theme [index.ts](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/theme/base/index.ts), [sizes.ts](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/theme/base/sizes.ts) and [space.ts](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/theme/base/space.ts).

Answer (score 1):

So I don't see this in any documentation, but the key you want to use to override (or add to) sizes is actually `space` and not `sizes`. I found this by going through the NativeBase theme source on GitHub.

```js
const myCustomTheme = extendTheme({
  space: {
    '0': 0, // NB use string keys... not sure if that matters.
    '1': 16,
    '2': 32,
    // and so on
  }
})
```

As for the `rem` question, you could add `2rem` as a custom size/space, but it would not run your function. So if you wanted something like `1.5rem`, it would have to be "hard coded" as far as I can tell.

You could go the code generated route if you have/need a lot of options:

```js
/** 
 * Generates 10 sizes at every 0.5rem
 * Change Array(x) to customize the number of sizes.
 * For larger/smaller steps, change the factor of idx (idx/2)
 **/
space: {
  '0': 0,
  '1rem': 16,
  '2rem': 32,
  // or...
  ...Array.from(Array(10).keys()).reduce((acc, _itm, idx) => {
    if (idx === 0) return acc;
    acc[`${idx/2}rem`] = idx / 2 * 8;
    return acc;
  }, {}),
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I was planning something like that in the beginning. In the end, I instead created a `rem` function to make the conversion, so I don't need to hardcode tons of values, considering I want to use decimals too.